A game I might have read about, Kasparov had to analyse an opening line from scratch and ended up winning anyway?
If my memory isn't tricking me, didn't Kasparov once get a game where early in the opening he didn't know the line, so he sat down for 45 minutes and worked out that the best move is Qc7, and went on to win? Is this what happened? I seem to remember reading that somewhere. I can't find it on Google though.
